# Quiero utilizar la api de google Shopping result para scrapear data de tiendas online

Tags: python, vscode, google-api, web-scrapping

Quiero utilizar la api de Google shopping result para obtener datos de zapatillas en chile quiero hacerlo en Python y por lo que he investigado la api ya mencionada es la mejor si alguien me puede ayudar a comenzar estaría agradecido.

Comment: Hola, parece que estás buscando un tutorial, Stack overflow es más bien para preguntas puntuales..